# Searchable spinner doesn't search after space

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm using a searchable spinner library in my app.
The custom library I using is

```
com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1
```

I'm getting values to spinner from API. The problem I am facing is whenever I search for a keyword after a space is not working. For example I have these data in my spinner

1. GLASS PIPE
2. GLASS SHEET
3. GLASS PLATE

and if i searched "GLASS", The three data will appear. But whenever I search for 
"GLASS PIPE", no result will appear.Help me to solve this.

**MY CODE BINDNG DATA TO SPINNER**

```
         ArrayList<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InsertRequisition.this, R.layout.item_spinner_black, employeeNames);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
            employeeSpinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.employee_name_value);

            for (int i=0;i<common.dataArrayList.size();i++){
               String[] data = new String[3];

                data[0]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[0];
                data[1]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[1];
                data[2]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[2];

                employeeList.add(data);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<employeeList.size();i++){
                employeeNames.add(employeeList.get(i)[1]+" - "+employeeList.get(i)[2]);
            }
            employeeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);

        }
```

**My Spinner code**

```
<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
        android:id="@+id/company_name_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You should post an issue on https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/issues

Comment: You are using an library. If that code was your's then you can solve it. 
Either ask in this library  issues. Or clone this library and solve out the List Filtering.

Comment: @Khemraj is there a better searchable spinner libraray?

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=searchable+spinner

Comment: @AndroDevil try AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: @TejpalBh bro can you help me to implemet autocompleteTextview in above code?

Answer (score 1):

Check following code for AutoCompleteTextView

```
    autoCompleteTextView=findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewID);
    employeeNames  = new ArrayList<String>();

    // getdata & store in dataList

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, employeeNames );
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String selectedStr  = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }
    });
```

Comment: check spelling and number of spaces you are providing.. In my case it works properly even after item having spaces in it